# Call Python Requests module through proxy to my own computer

Tags: python, heroku, flask, proxy, python-requests

I have a Flask/Python app hosted on Heroku, and one of my features attempts to call an external API service using the 'requests' module. The service explicitly states that they do not allow for requests to come in from AWS/Heroku servers, however, the request can successfully come in from my local computer.

My question is, can I set up a proxy to my own computer, so that when my app calls this API it looks like it is coming from my computer instead of Heroku?

I tried using the 'Proximo' and 'QuotaGuard Static' services on Heroku, but the API did not accept requests from either of those proxies. I want the proxy to come directly from my IP address - how can I do that? For example, can I modify this bit of code to accomplish this? Is there something I need to set up on my local computer?

```
import requests

proxies = {
'http': 'http://**', **What do I put here??
'https': 'http://**',
}

requests.get('http://example.org', proxies=proxies)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't use a proxy. You may not even need one.

```
import requests

requests.get('http://example.org')
```